# The type arguments for method 'PowerShell.Invoke<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-services

I have a windows service(.net framework) project where I am running a powershell script. When I run the same code in the console app, there is no problem. but here I get the error "The type arguments for method 'PowerShell.Invoke()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

````
    {
        private Thread workerThread;
        private bool running;
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service1));
    
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            running = true;
            workerThread = new Thread(WorkerThreadProc);
            workerThread.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            running = false;
            workerThread.Join();
        }

        private static void WorkerThreadProc()
        {
            bool running = true;
            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();

                while (running)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string powerShellCommand = "Get-Process";
                        string output = RunPowerShellCommand(powerShellCommand);
                        string directoryPath = @"C:\HttpConnector\Output";
                        string fileName = "PsOutput.txt";
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);

                        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                        }

                        WriteToFile(filePath, output);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error("Hata oluştu.", ex);
                    }

                    TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    Thread.Sleep(interval);
                }

                runspace.Close();
            }
            }
     
        private static string RunPowerShellCommand(string command)
        {
            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();

                using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;
                    ps.AddScript(command);

                    try
                    {
                        var results = ps.Invoke();
                        var output = GetObjectInfo(results);
                        return output;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error("Hata oluştu: " + ex.ToString());
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


     
        private static string GetObjectInfo(Collection<PSObject> psObjects)
        {
            string output = string.Empty;

            foreach (var psObject in psObjects)
            {
                output += $"{psObject.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}";

            }

            return output;
        }```

Added;
Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
System.Management.Automation
````

Comment: What happens when you follow the advice in the error message (eg. `ps.Invoke<PSObject>()`)?

Comment: As you apparently hosting this from PowerShell, using PowerShell cmdlets and manage PowerShell scripts. Why not writing this in PowerShell?

Comment: Compare the contents of the two ```*.csproj``` files and check you've got the same versions of all your package references, etc, in both. Also open the console-based project and hover the mouse over the ```Invoke()``` part of ```ps.Invoke()``` and check whether it's calling the ```Invoke()``` or ```Invoke<T>()``` overload, then do the same in the service-based project and make sure they're binding to the same overload...